# Installing xampp

Tags: php, installation, xampp, upgrade

I tried to install xampp (I downloaded xampp-win32-upgrade-1.7.2-1.7.3). After I finish extracting it gives fatal error :

> failed opening required : G:\xampp\install\xampp_xampp_php'
>    in G:\xampp\setup_xampp.bat on line 33

Did I download wrong archive. I'm installing on windows 7 64 bit.I don't have any preinstalled xampp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you downloaded the 32 bit version, hence the 'win32' in the name.

Comment: Not true, you can run 32 bit apps in 64 OSs (although they might run slower than their native 64b counterparts)

Comment: That should not be a problem. W7x64 can handle 32bit apps. I use 32bit xampp myself.

Comment: it help says it supports 64 bit

Comment: Yea, you're right, but this particular one gives errors on some 64 bit machines. I just read an article about it.

Comment: Do a search in google for 'xampp 64 bit' - you can probably find a solution there.

Answer (score 4):

Uhm just out of curiosity, if you don't have xampp installed, why did you get the upgrade version instead of the final one? Get the basic package instead

Comment: Yes you did, try the link i just placed here.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try a new WAMP Stack called AMPPS by Softaculous.

http://www.ampps.com/download

Answer (score 0):

You can download xampp from Apache-friends. In there select your operating system such as windows / Linux etc.. Then in the download section click on xampp. Then you will see the link called "installer" click on it. and your download will start and it.

Download and install the software to your computer. If the application control start automatically it is fine. If not you can go to the folder where the xampp is downloaded and then check for xampp control click on it and open it.

Then what you have to do is starting Apache to access to our localhost. So you click on the start button right in front of Apache. And that you will see it starts running.

Answer (score 0):

It is there described properly. [How to install xampp](http://www.elcaro-guide.com/php-blog/basics-for-php-beginners). check it.

Answer (score 0):

I installed it on Windows 10 and it installs quite easily as long as you have the correct version. I only chose Apache and MariaDB during installation. As I am using an earlier version of MySQL and using IIS, I will have to modify the MySQL and Apache to work on my computer. Although the installation web site says MariaDB, I still see MySQL. Perhaps I need to upgrade to MariaDB.

Here you can find more details with some screen shots:
http://hodentek.blogspot.com/2015/11/installing-xampp-on-computer-running.html

Answer (score 0):

You just have to go to Xampp site and download new related version. it is easy to install

Comment: Please do not post answers to questions posted ages ago. The person who asked the question must have solved the problem by now don't you think ? Try to answer fresh questions to improve your reputation as well as knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

uninstall your xampp, and craete backup your file , install 64 bit version

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when the Downloaded archive is damaged.
Please follow some steps it may help you:

- Just delete temporary files in you System using Run Command

  - `RUN-> TEMP`
  - `RUN-> %TEMP%`
- Download new archive (32 bit version is supported in 64 bit).
- Restart your PC
- Try to install if problem persists check your PC's antivirus